# Combining Multiple Columns

Tags: sql

I have three simple tables as shown below:

```
+----+-------------+  +----+-----------+  +----+---------------+
| artists          |  | albums         |  | songs              |
+----+-------------+  +----+-----------+  +----+---------------+
| id | name        |  | id | name      |  | id | name          |
+----+-------------+  +----+-----------+  +----+---------------+
| 0  | The Beatles |  | 0  | Help!     |  | 0  | Help!         |
| 1  | Metallica   |  | 1  | Metallica |  | 1  | Enter Sandman |
+----+-------------+  +----+-----------+  +----+---------------+
```

And I would like a query to result in the following:

```
+--------+---------------+
| type   | name          |
+--------+---------------+
| artist | The Beatles   |
| artist | Metallica     |
| album  | Help!         |
| album  | Metallica     |
| song   | Help!         |
| song   | Enter Sandman |
+--------+---------------+
```

I am trying to use a `LIKE` query to search Artists, Albums, and Songs.

Right now I use the SQL below to grab the results from the three columns, then I use Ruby to bring them together in one object. I figure it would be much more efficient to use pure SQL rather than the interpreted language to return the results.

```
SELECT name FROM artists WHERE name LIKE 'something%'
SELECT name FROM albums WHERE name LIKE 'something%'
SELECT name FROM songs WHERE name LIKE 'something%'
```

I am not so great with SQL and have been struggling with this for a few days and was wondering if anyone on here could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could, as others have suggested, use UNION.  The semantics of UNION, however, force the database to eliminate duplicate rows which generally requires a sort operation.  Since you know that each query necessarily returns non-duplicate rows, it would be more efficient to use UNION ALL.  Something like

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT 'artists' as type, name 
          FROM artists 
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'albums' as type, name 
          FROM albums
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'songs' as type, name 
          FROM songs)
 WHERE name LIKE 'something%'
```

Whatever database engine you are using should be able to push the predicate on `NAME` into each of the three branches that are being UNION ALL'ed together.  But it would be worth confirming that in the query plan.

Comment: I was thinking about how to go about exactly this with the other answers. Bravo!

Answer (score 2):

You can use UNION to join similar results together. Try this:

```
SELECT 'artist' as Type, name FROM artists WHERE name LIKE 'something%'
UNION SELECT 'album' as Type, name FROM albums WHERE name LIKE 'something%'
UNION SELECT 'song' as Type, name FROM songs WHERE name LIKE 'something%'
```

Comment: I have actually come across this answer before. The problem here is I need to know which table each result is actually in. Thanks for your quick answer, though! Edit: Bah, I missed the `AS` part of the query. =p

Answer (score 1):

You should use union to merge the results in a single resultset, and also hardcode the type you want according to table..

```
SELECT 'artist' as [type], name FROM artists WHERE name LIKE 'something%'
UNION
SELECT 'album' as [type], name FROM albums WHERE name LIKE 'something%'
UNION
SELECT 'song' as [type], name FROM songs WHERE name LIKE 'something%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use union with constant string as a column for the result, like

```
      select 'artist' as type, name as name from artists
union select 'album' as type, name as name from albums
union select 'song' as type, name as name from songs
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 'artists' as type, name from artists where name like '%something%'
union 
select 'albums' , name from albums where ...
union 
select 'songs', name from songs where ...
```